# Is it "ignorance in something" or "ignorance on something"?

Tags: word-usage

> Let's eat grandma. Let's eat, grandma.
>
> Over millions of grandmas die each day because of our ignorance **in** using commas. Commas save lives! Use commas now!

Should that *in* actually be *on*? How do I find out which preposition to use here?

Comment: This would be a question for Ell (English Language Learners).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ignorance of" is most common, but other prepositions are acceptable, giving slightly different meanings. Some meanings are:

- "Ignorance **of** using commas". We are unaware of the existence of the subject 'using commas'
- "Ignorance **about** using commas". We are ignorant of the way in which commas should be used.
- "Ignorance **in** using commas". We display ignorance when we use commas.

The distinctions are pretty subtle, but all are acceptable.

"Ignorance on" is incorrect.

Comment: I find it hard to criticise answers which I fully agree with for lack of supporting evidence. But since I criticise those I think are wrong or unbalanced for that reason, I have to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The normal preposition after ignorance is "of". "about" is also possible.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ignorance

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - A typo, I meant Ell. Going to correct it.

Comment: No, I was referring to giving a LMGTFY 'answer' here at all, when OP has shown no signs of research. Though DJClayworth has given a response which would be very good (though answering the final, broader question) if supported.

Comment: Thanks for adding a source. This(http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/ignorance) is where I ended up at(Correct me if I'm wrong with this one, too. lol) and didn't bother with the examples given since I initially overlooked the use for "of" with only "in" and "on"(which I now know is incorrect) in mind.